# Is it possible to get empty array value via $_GET?

Tags: php, arrays, get

Is it possible to get empty array(array with 0 items) value via `$_GET`?

Is it possible with direct value setting?

```
count($_GET['param'])==0
```

Comment: @kingkero, no, isset value checks that value is null or unexists. But array() is not null value.

Comment: @RakeshSharma , ok, i could rephrase: how I could send value via url to get empty array value on php side?

Comment: looking for empty($_GET['param']) or simple $get = $_GET['param']; whether it's null or not

Comment: @RakeshSharma, ok, i need array with 0 items.

Comment: as simple as this: http://httpbin.org/get?a=[]

Comment: @Prasanth, it's not an array, it's a string

Comment: you can get an array with at least one empty element.

Comment: @JackyCheng you will not ALWAYS have string in case your query string is something like "test.php?param[]=blablabla" array(1) {["param"]=>array(1) {[0]=>string(9) "blablabla"}}

Comment: @sectus, ?a=[] will be translated to an array. $_GET['a'].

Comment: @Shurik thanks for pointing out, been working with pure string url for too long I've forgotten about it.

Comment: no offence, but I am amazed that OP with over 6k rep will still need to ask these kind of question that can be answered by google and some quick research. (and in such a confusing question format).

Comment: @JacobCohen , are you sure? Recheck it, please, I have have different result: `$_GET['a'] == '[]'` -- it just a string.

Comment: @JackyCheng , I do not know :^ ) It seems that documentation cannot provide me right answer. And it seems that I need to go deeper to PHP source code(but i am not с/с++ programer).

Comment: @sectus you are right '[]' is a string.

What I am talkin about is the url ?a=[] which will be translated to $_GET['a']. If you want to check if its empty array use the "empty" function.

Answer (score 1):

You just need an empty value  url = `myform.php?param=&param2=`

In form just let the value blank:

```
<input type='text' name='param' value ='' />
```

**For an empty array**:

url: `myform.php?param[]=&param2[some_key]=`

in form: `<input type='text' name='param[]' value ='' />`

**From Ajax:** (I remember this was so anti-intuitive and hard to search for):

```
ajax{
    ...
    data: {'params[]':'','params2[some_key]':''}
}
```

**Workaround**:
Just edit the back-end and if there is no data for `params` or it is not an array (null, empty whatever ..) just assign an empty string to it:

`$param = (isset($_GET['param']) && is_array($_GET['param']))? $_GET['param'] : array();`

**Update:**
I did few tests and it seems there is no way to put "nothing" in the request ussing a form or ajax.
`0`, `''`, `Null` are valid values for the `$_GET` but empty array is not even created. 
So to answer your question, it is **NOT possible** to get empty array value from the front-end.

There are few options to edit $_GET manually in the back-end:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_GET['param']) || !$_GET['param']){ //not set or (null,0,"")
        $_GET['param'] = array();
    }
    if(count($_GET['param'])==0){...}; // 0 if no 'param' was provided.
```

Comment: Thanks, but. `param[]=` is not empty array. It's array with one empty value. Also, I need to get array with 0 items without extra reassign.

Comment: Now that I reviewed.. it is good question, but it is NOT possible.
See my update.

Answer (score 0):

If array is empty or containing values that doesn't matters. Just declare a variable and pass the $_GET[] to the variable.

for example,

```
$para=$_GET['param'];
```

and now

```
if(is_array($para))
{
//  

} 
else{
$para=new array();
}
```

Comment: I need to avoid extra assigns and conditions.

Comment: you don't need to else block. just use if(count($para)<1){ // your code } else { //having value greater than zero }

Answer (score 0):

passing empty array via GET is not possible under normal situation. That said, I can think of a really rare way that the checking you used will return true.

```
http://domain.com/receiver?param=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D
```

The above is basically a serialized and urlencoded empty array with the key 'param'

if the target server have some sort of filter that auto unserialize all incoming data, then it might happen.
(or something like the below)

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
$_GET[$key] = unserialize($value);
}

count($_GET['param'])==0
```

I know this is a far fetch but it is possible, maybe some private test server that only handles serialized data but accidentally open to public e.t.c.
That said, it is still only passing a serialized empty array instead of a empty array itself. But let's be honest, this answer is more like a joke/fun answer that tries to point out under some very rare case

```
count($_GET['param'])==0
```

will return true (Without actively assigning values @ server side)